# Select Groups And the Users That Belong To Those Groups

Tags: html, laravel

```
{!! Form::select('task_assign_to', \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Roles\EloquentRole::whereIn('id', [1,2,3])->with('users')->lists('name', 'id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'task_assign_to', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
```

I have it displaying each of the Roles but under each of the roles need to have the users that have that as their role. I'm not sure what I need to do so it'll display the users. This is utilizing Laravel.

For example if we have 3 roles. Owners, Admins, Users and there's so many users in each of those roles this is how I want it to display.

```
<select>
   <optgroup>Owners</optgroup>
   <option>Owner 1</option>
   <option>Owner 2</option>
   <option>Owner 3</option>
   <optgroup>Admins</optgroup>
   <option>Admin 1</option>
   <option>Admin 2</option>
   <option>Admin 3</option>
   <optgroup>Users</optgroup>
   <option>User 1</option>
   <option>User 2</option>
   <option>User 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to only get the users that have the specified role?

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do is get the roles with ids of 1,2, and 3 and then retrieve the users that have those roles and then use the role names as the option group and display the users under each of those roles.